# Visual Studio 2008 Designer crashes randomly for my Devexpress Reports

Tags: visual-studio-2008, devexpress, designer

I have a program written in VB that has DataDynamics ActiveReports as well as DevExpress reports in it. Yesterday when I started working it wouldn't let me use my DevExpress reports with the designer. I restarted Visual Studio and it worked fine. Today I am working on the same reports and Visual Studio won't let me use Designer for any of the DevExpress reports again. Each of the reports Designer is complaining about the same method not being found (DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.BandCollection.AddRange).

I have no idea how to fix this.

Here is the call stack :

```
Instances of this error (1)  

at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by deleting the designer file for one of the reports, `filename.Designer.vb`, and then refetching it from the subversion repository. I then got a bunch of errors in visual studio because it didn't see the new file so I just had to restart Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your project references different versions of our assemblies or so on.  Please use the ProjectConverter tool to upgrade your project to the Suite version you are using.  Also, please make certain that there are no old DevExpress DLLs in the bin folder.  This should help.  One more idea - check that you are not using assemblies which reference old DevExpress assemblies. If not, try to reinstall the installation.

Comment: I rant the ProjectConverter, checked my DLLs and checked the assemblies... I have also restarted Visual Studio several times and my computer. There has got to be something less drastic than reinstalling the installation.

Comment: Please try to debug the VS as it is explained in the article available at:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/ViewKBIssue.aspx?kbid=A948

When the debugger stops, please take a look at the list of loaded modules (Debug-->Windows-->Modules).  This list should explain which DLL is wrong.

Comment: Thanks I got it. Just had to delete one of the designer files and refetch from SVN.